# Access file using Java in Windows with illegal Character in path

Tags: java, windows, path

I am using a Windows machine and Java. I'm just trying to backup a file, but I ran into an issue with an illegal character in the path ("#"). I really tried and I'm stuck. I rewrote it trying all the variations I could find or think of. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class SyncActionMachine {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
    String MSI_one, MSI_two, dropBox;
    GetDate getDate = new GetDate();

    MSI_one = "C:\\Users\\Brian\\AppData\\Roaming\\Macromedia\\Flash Player\\#SharedObjects\\Q2965ZS7\\localhost\\ActionMachine.sol";
    MSI_two = "C:\\Users\\Brian\\Desktop\\test.txt";
    dropBox = "C:\\Users\\Brian\\Dropbox\\Action Machine History\\ActionMachine.sol";

    File source = new File(MSI_one);
    File destination = new File(dropBox);

    // Attempt #1 using string with special characters  
    try {
        Files.copy(source.toPath(), destination.toPath());
    } catch (IOException iOException) {
        System.out.println("Didn't work: " + iOException);
    }

    // Attempt #2 using URI - not really sure how to use it.
    URI uri;
    uri = new URI("file:///C:/Users/Brian/AppDate/Roaming/Macromedia/Flash%20Player/%23SharedObjects/Q2965ZS7/localhost/ActionMachine.sol");
    Path uriSelfMadePath = Paths.get(uri);
    try {
        Files.copy(uriSelfMadePath, destination.toPath());
    } catch (IOException iOException) {
        System.out.println("Didn't work: " + iOException);
    }

    // Attempt #3 Suggestion from Aurasphere. Thanks again for quick response.
    // Not sure what I'm suppose to do with the URL
    String thePath = MSI_one;
    thePath = URLEncoder.encode(thePath, "UTF-8");
    Path aurasphereThePath = Paths.get(thePath);
    try {
        Files.copy(aurasphereThePath, destination.toPath());
    } catch (IOException iOException) {
        System.out.println("Didn't work: " + iOException);
    }

    // Attempt #4 build path using Patha and passing in augruments separately
    Path pathOneByOne = Paths.get("C:", "Users", "Brian", "AppDate", "Roaming", "Macromedia", "Flash Player",
            "#SharedObjects", "Q2965ZS7", "localhost", "ActionMachine.sol");
    try {
        Files.copy(pathOneByOne, destination.toPath());
    } catch (IOException iOException) {
        System.out.println("Didn't work: " + iOException);
    }

    // Seeing what all these path's look like
    URL fileUrl = source.toURI().toURL();
    URI fileUri = source.toURI();
    System.out.println("------------Path Print out------------------");
    System.out.println("URLEncoder : " + thePath);
    Path from = Paths.get(fileUri);
    System.out.println("URL : " + fileUrl);
    System.out.println("URI : " + fileUri);
    System.out.println("source: " + source);

}

}
```

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: # is not an illegal character on Windows.  What error(s) do you get,and when?

Comment: You are right Harry, I phrased it wrong.  It guess I should have used special character. The error is file not found in all test cases.

Answer (score 0):

Just use URLEncode:

```
String thePath = "your_path";
thePath = URLEncoder.encode(thePath, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Thank you for the amazingly fast reply.  I took your suggestion and searched for a while, I just don't know how to implement it.

Comment: At first glance, at least, this seems unlikely to help, since Windows doesn't use UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone that looked and commented.  Must have been some sleep derived moment.  Anyway here is the source, it worked fine.  Turned out # was a big deal, I'm not even sure what my hang up was.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
    String MSI_one, MSI_two, dropBox;
    GetDate getDate = new GetDate();

    MSI_one = "C:\\Users\\Brian\\AppData\\Roaming\\Macromedia\\Flash Player\\#SharedObjects\\Q2965ZS7\\localhost\\ActionMachine.sol";
    MSI_two = "C:\\Users\\brian\\AppData\\Roaming\\Macromedia\\Flash Player\\#SharedObjects\\HSTARDTM\\localhost\\ActionMachine.sol";
    dropBox = "C:\\Users\\brian\\Dropbox\\Action Machine History\\";

    // Create new file name for backup file 
    dropBox = dropBox + "ActionMachine-" + getDate.today() + ".sol";

    File source = new File(MSI_two);
    File destination = new File(dropBox);
    copyNewFile cf = new copyNewFile(source, destination);
}


public class copyNewFile {
  public copyNewFile(File source, File dest) throws IOException {
    CopyOption[] options = new CopyOption[]{
        StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING,
        StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES
    };
    Files.copy(source.toPath(), dest.toPath(), options);

    System.out.println("File sucessfully copied.");
  }
}
```